# One attribute request always get 400 in @WebMvcTest

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, mockmvc

I have this controller endpoint

```
@PostMapping("/{productId}/activation/")
    public ResponseEntity<ProductResponse> toggleProductActivation(@PathVariable("productId") UUID productId,
                                                                   @RequestBody @Valid ToggleProductActivationRequest toggleProductActivationRequest)
            throws ApplicationException {
        var product = toggleProductActivationUseCase.handle(productCommandAssembler.assembleToggleProductActivationCommand(
                toggleProductActivationRequest, productId));
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                             .body(productResponseAssembler.assembleProductResponse(product));
    }
```

the corresponding request POJO with only one field

```
@Builder
@Getter
public class ToggleProductActivationRequest {

    @NotNull
    private Boolean active;
}
```

and finally my unit test

```
@WebMvcTest(value = ProductAdminController.class)
class ProductAdminControllerTest {

    private static final String EXCEPTION_MESSAGE = "Exception";

    @Autowired
    protected ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @MockBean
    private ToggleProductActivationUseCase toggleProductActivationUseCase;
    @MockBean
    private ProductCommandAssembler productCommandAssembler;
    @MockBean
    private ProductResponseAssembler productResponseAssembler;

    @Test
    void whenToggleProductActivation_givenProductDoesNotExist_thenReturnNotFound404() throws Exception {
        // given
        var productId = UUID.randomUUID();
        var toggleProductActivationRequest = givenToggleProductActivationRequest();
        var toggleProductActivationCommand = mock(ToggleProductActivationCommand.class);
        when(productCommandAssembler.assembleToggleProductActivationCommand(any(ToggleProductActivationRequest.class),
                                                                            eq(productId),
                                                                            eq(null))).thenReturn(toggleProductActivationCommand);
        when(toggleProductActivationUseCase.handle(toggleProductActivationCommand)).thenThrow(new NotFoundException(
                EXCEPTION_MESSAGE));

        // when & then
        mockMvc.perform(post("/api/v1.0/admin/products/" + productId.toString() + "/activation/")
                                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                                .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(toggleProductActivationRequest)))
               .andExpect(status().isNotFound())
               .andExpect(jsonPath("$.httpStatus").value(404))
               .andExpect(jsonPath("$.reason").value(EXCEPTION_MESSAGE));
    }

    private ToggleProductActivationRequest givenToggleProductActivationRequest() {
        return ToggleProductActivationRequest.builder()
                                             .active(true)
                                             .build();
    }
}
```

When running this test, I always get a 400 Bad Request

To check if I was not driving myself crazy, I tried this request POJO
I just added a useless field test and this time no 400, I get the expected unit test result

```
@Builder
@Getter
public class ToggleProductActivationRequest {

    @NotNull
    private Boolean active;

    private String test;
}
```

What's going on here.
A Spring restriction? why would they do that?
A bug? then I'll report it

Do you guys have any idea?

I could just pass the activation info a query param but I'd like to keep it that way

Comment: Check if `/api/v1.0/admin/` is actually correct and remove tralinig `/` in `/activation/` both in test and mapping

Comment: Also you should see debug details in the console where you can see what did you actually POSTed, check that to see if the payload is as intended. (if not, add `.andDo(print())`)

Answer (score 0):

I just find out that the issue was on Lombok side:

I had to add all the constructors

```
@Builder
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ToggleProductActivationRequest {

    @NotNull
    private Boolean active;
}
```

when I have more than 1 attribute in the POJO, no need to do that